# How to output my SvelteKit app in index.html when I run `npm run build`

Tags: svelte, vite, sveltekit

I am building a simple sveltekit application. Is working as expected on the development server but I am not getting the expected output when I run `npm run build`. Here is the setup:

- I am using the `@sveltejs/adapter-static` adapter.
- I am setting `export const ssr = false;` in `+layout.js`
- I am setting `fallback: "index.html"` in `svelte.config.js`

The problem is the `index.html` it outputs is just the basic 'Welcome to SvelteKit' page and not my application that I see when I run the development server.

I just need to run a simple SPA and I don't care for SSR but I do need the routing in sveltekit.
I am also wondering the purposes of the fallback page and I can't see any documentation on how it can be customized.

I feel like any SPA outputting its app in an `index.html` is the basic and wondering why it is so hard.

Answer (score 0):

An SPA is rendered on the client and by setting a `fallback` you're telling SvelteKit to generate an SPA. This would give you a near-empty HTML page that is then rendered on the client with client-side navigation between routes.

Do you instead mean that you want a fully pre-rendered site? If so, then you probably want SSG, which you can [learn about here](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-static).

The key here is to set `fallback` to `null` and set `export const prerender = true` in `+layout.ts`.

If you do in fact want an SPA with no prerendering, then you can look at the [docs on setting up an SPA here](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/single-page-apps)